# How do you center a text-align=left text in a table cell in angular (css table)?

Tags: css

How do you center a `text-align=left` text in a table cell in angular (css table)?

EDIT: What I was trying to ask was. How do you have left align text but centered in the middle of a table cell.

Comment: can you provide code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question, as this will help the community better understand your specific issue and provide you with a good answer.

Comment: This isn't an angular question. It's a simple html/css question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is use for table data cell

```
td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

This one for table header cell

```
th {
      text-align: center;
    }
```

Comment: I see I was marked down for this question. I do not think I worded this well.  how do you text-align: left. and then have it in the center of the cell?